# How to find duplicate rows in gnumeric or Libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice, gnumeric

I have gnumeric and libreoffice calc. How to find duplicate rows? if I could use libreoffice, it's better, but anything is good for me.

I have the latest stable version of both software

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=calc+duplicates

Comment: By 'find' do you want the duplicate rows to be hidden/removed?

Comment: @Wilf i want to take notes of them, later on I want to remove them

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This a way you can hide and then remove duplicate rows (or 'records') in Libreoffice Calc

- Go to the worksheet that has the duplicate entries, and select **'Data'** > **'Filter'** > **'Standard Filter**' *(it seems to automatically select the data in the sheet that it will filter, you may want to do this manually beforehand)*. 
  Then in the box that pops up, select the column *(Field - entering multiple 'Fields' may be possible)*, and as the value(s) enter 'Not Empty'.
  Then under the **'Options**' pop-down menu, select **'No duplications'** - you may want to select other options like *'Case-sensitive'*, *'Copy results to'*, etc as well.
  [image]
- It should then filter the data, and hide any duplicate records. You can copy this to a new worksheet if you want to have the dataset without duplicates (instead of the dupes just being hidden). 
  You can reset the filter if necessary by going to **'Data'** > **'Filter'** > **'Reset Filter'**

  [image]

This worked with Libreoffice 4.2.5.2
The help page for 'Standard Filter' is [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Standard_Filter).

Comment: This kind of works, with a workaround, but it's not really what was asked for. He asked specifically to *find* the duplicates.

Answer (score 28):

In order to find duplicate rows and their respective counts on MS Excel or LibreOffice you can use following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "=" & A2)
```

It will provide count of duplicate records in the cell formula is applied on.

Explanation of formula:

1. A:A is the range in which duplicate comparison will execute.
2. "=" is the operator to compare records for duplicacy.
3. & A2 is the value which will be compared in the range i.e; A:A (Column A)

You can use filter to check duplicate records with X no. of duplicacy.

Check screenshot for application of this formula:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot ... let's upvote this answer !

Answer (score 15):

To detect the duplicates in a column there is a solution on [www.techrepublic.com](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-find-duplicates-in-excel/).
It is written for MS Excel, but it works as well in **gnumeric** and **LibreOffice Calc**.

Its mainly about this formula:

`=if(countif(e$4:e$9;e4)>1;'yes';'no')`

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend editing this answer to expand it with a summary or restatement of the important information from [the linked page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-find-duplicates-in-excel/), so this answer is self contained. (That [is considered preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to an answer that only makes sense if people read the externally linked page.)

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Libreoffice calc :(

Comment: @Mr.T Can U tell me more about the issue ? Can U provide your file ?

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates in any range/column/cells etc.
Go to Format tab - Conditional - Condition. This opens a dialog box and select duplicates and set the Accent to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

To find entire duplicate rows,

1. **concatenate** the whole row and
2. then use the **countif** (mentioned elsewhere) on that :-)